# How to make and correctly update progress bar in cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game that uses a progress bar to inform player of level of certain stats of the player. For example hunger, when it starts at zero and slowly adds up to maximum bar. When he eats the hunger reduces.

I tried implementing as progressBar, but it works wrong, as the bar expands both ways, and I need it to grow one side only. Also I had hard time setting the bar, since it uses actions.

Is there an easy way to do it?

I have a class Pet and it has int hunger (0-100). I want the bar to be showing hunger.

```
hungerBar = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"redbar.png"];
    CCLabelTTF *hungerLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hunger:" fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:25];
    [hungerLabel setColor:ccc3(255, 255, 255)];

//    CGPoint temp = ccp(250, 300);
//    hungerBar.position = temp;
 //   [self addChild:hungerBar];
    CGPoint temp2 = ccp(250, 320);
    [hungerLabel setPosition:temp2];
    [self addChild:hungerLabel];

    CCSprite *bar = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"redbar.png"];
    powerBar= [CCProgressTimer progressWithSprite:bar];
    powerBar.type = kCCProgressTimerTypeBar;
    powerBar.position = ccp(-30, -10);
    powerBar.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
    powerBar.percentage = 20; // (0 - 100)
    [hungerLabel addChild:powerBar];
```

Added source.

Comment: are you able to show your progressBar code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Before cocos2d 2.0, you should be able to just use CCProgressTimer of type: *kCCProgressTimerTypeHorizontalBarLR*.

```
CCProgressTimer* powerBar= [CCProgressTimer progressWithFile:@"fullbar.png"];
powerBar.type = kCCProgressTimerTypeHorizontalBarLR;
powerBar.percentage = 0; // (0 - 100)
```

To vary your hunger level, simply set the *percentage* property of your bar.

**EDITED:**

Ok, with cocos2d 2.0, it seems that such a type is no longer available. To get a left-to-right-bar, you will need to set the new but somewhat confusing *midpoint* and *barChangeRate* properties ([cocos2D 2.0 documentation link](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.0.0/interface_c_c_progress_timer.html#a9244a39378508fe0da6436e7db1c3724)):

```
CCProgressTimer* powerBar= [CCProgressTimer progressWithSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"fullbar.png"]];
powerBar.type = kCCProgressTimerTypeBar;
powerBar.midpoint = ccp(0,0); // starts from left
powerBar.barChangeRate = ccp(1,0); // grow only in the "x"-horizontal direction
powerBar.percentage = 0; // (0 - 100)
```

See if these helps!

Comment: This doesn't work in Cocos2d 2. There is no method like this, only method with sprite, i made it, its ok, but the bar growth both ways and I need only one way. Also there is no such type in cocos2d 2, There is only following type -      CCSprite *bar = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"redbar.png"];
    powerBar= [CCProgressTimer progressWithSprite:bar];
    powerBar.type = kCCProgressTimerTypeBar;

Comment: Yea, apparently they removed the type in 2.0. See my edited answer:)